# Is this a more optimized alternative to instantiate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, object-pooling

I'm trying to make a custom object pooling class (this is my first time trying to avoid using `Instantiate()`.
I know object pooling is objectively better than instantiating but I'm worried that the way I set it up might actually be worse than instantiating since I have a **long** List of gameobjects, and in order to find a reusable gameobject I have to use a `foreach` loop to loop through all the elements of the list.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] GameObject redHurtEffect;
    [SerializeField] GameObject Arrow;
   static List<GameObject> pooledObjects = new List<GameObject>(2);
    private void Awake()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            GameObject theEffect = Instantiate(redHurtEffect);
            pooledObjects.Add(theEffect);
            theEffect.SetActive(false);
            

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 550; i++)
        {
            GameObject theEffect = Instantiate(Arrow);
            pooledObjects.Add(theEffect);
            theEffect.SetActive(false);
        }
     
    }
    public static void Spawn(GameObject prefab, Vector3 spawnWhere, Quaternion? rotation =null, int repetitions =1, Vector2? setScale = null)
    {
        if (repetitions == 1)
        {
            Debug.Log(prefab.name);
            GameObject spawned = prefabToPooled(prefab);
            spawned.SetActive(true);
            spawned.transform.position = spawnWhere;
            if(setScale!=null || setScale.HasValue)
            {
                spawned.transform.localScale = setScale.Value;
            }
            if (rotation.HasValue)
            {
                spawned.transform.rotation = rotation.Value;
            }
      
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < repetitions+1; i++)
            {
           // convertedPrefab.SetActive(true);
        // convertedPrefab.transform.position = spawnWhere;

            }
        }
       
    } 
    public static GameObject Spawn(GameObject prefab, Vector3 spawnWhere, Quaternion? rotation = null, Vector2? setScale = null, Transform parent = null)
    {

          GameObject spawned =  prefabToPooled(prefab);
        Transform spawnedTransform = spawned.GetComponent<Transform>();
            Debug.Log(prefab.name);
        spawned.SetActive(true);
            spawnedTransform.position = spawnWhere;
        if (rotation.HasValue)
        {
            spawnedTransform.rotation = rotation.Value;
        }
        if (setScale != null || setScale.HasValue)
        {
            spawnedTransform.localScale = setScale.Value;
        }
        spawnedTransform.SetParent(parent);
        

        return prefabToPooled(prefab);
        
       
      
        
    }
    public static void rePool(GameObject gameObj)
    {
        gameObj.transform.SetParent(null);
        pooledObjects.Add(gameObj);
        gameObj.SetActive(false);
    }
   
    
    public static GameObject prefabToPooled(GameObject prefab)
    {
        
        string prefabName = prefab.name;
        foreach (var item in pooledObjects)
        {
            if(item.name.Contains(prefabName))
            {
                item.SetActive(true);
                pooledObjects.Remove(item);
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The performance seems the same? I tried fake instantiating arrows every frame using the object pooling, and then I tried normally instantiating, and unless I'm blind the results seemed to be the same.
Also I'm worried if it'll be slower since I just started using this, I have so much more items to add to the game. The `pooledObjects` List might contain thousands or even tens of thousands of elements (since I want to add treasure like "diamond crown, emerald crown, coin, necklace" and I'd like to have many of those per level)
Would `foreach` looping through those thousands of elements be worse than instantiating?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you insist on rolling your own solution? This is a pretty commonly used system and because of that there are many decently made yet simple Unity pooling systems on github.

Comment: You can also use a `Queue<T>` instead of a `List<T>` and push/pop accordingly; thus no iterations.